# How to set global options for components with angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I'm using the component mydatepicker in angular2 https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker.
What is the best practice to set a global option for this?
For example, if you always want the option dateFormat = 'dd/mm/yyyy' I could create my own component with this option and then put the DatePicker in my template using `<my-component>` instead of `<my-datepicker>`.
But I'm sure it's a very bad way to do that.

More in general i should insert the component in the 'myview.html' template using  when myDatePickerOptions is set into 'myview.ts'.
But I'would like to edit the global options for all the instance of my-date-picker and preserve the chance of editing the options for individual instances.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to handle your scenario.

1) If you don't want to change the value of your configuration.

In this case you have to define the one common configuration object.

```
export const CommonConfig = {
    datepickerConfig: {
    dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    displayTime: true,
    ....
    },
    // here you can put your other configuration
}
```

This exported constant will be accessible via import statement in your component, service.

```
import { CommonConfig } from './<path where Common config is define>';
```

2) If you want to change the value of your configuration from application.

In this case you have to create one global level service and which is inject in app.module.ts file's provider section. When we defining global service into the provider section of app.module.ts there is only one instance will be available for entire application. So, you can access any data/configuration from this service or you can set/modify the existing configuration.

I hope this will helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Create your component and pass your config options from  parent component. Set a picker.defaults.ts file for defaults and export a const from that. So you can write 
@Input pickerConfig:any;
In ngOnInit,
this.pickerConfig = defaultConfig;

Comment: Thanks RemyaJ, probably I don't understand cause I'm new in ng2 but what I would like to avoid is create my own component just for define global settings.

Comment: Yes then you dont have to create a component for this. Create a common config file and then import this and use it where you initialize your picker